# Authenticate an external app using IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a requirement where I have to verify if the credentials provided by user is same as any IAM users/roles.

Does amazon have any api that can help in achieving this? Knowing all the user and validating password?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this.

Get the required jar: Get amazon aws sdk

Java code:

```
try{
    BasicAWSCredentials _basicAWS = new BasicAWSCredentials(_accessKey, _secretKey);
    AmazonIdentityManagementClient client = new AmazonIdentityManagementClient(_basicAWS);
    GetUserResult res = client.getUser();
    return true;
}catch(Exception ex){
    return false;
}
```